# How to add a strategy in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Actually, SparkSession has a function to do this.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.withExtensions(f => f.injectPlannerStrategy(new MyStrategy(_))) .
```

But in `pyspark`, I don't find any similar function.